# Login ID and Password using core data iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, authentication, uitableview

I am creating doing a project with core data.

Now my first view is Login/password in table view controller.

As soon as the user hits done, i want my app to compare the login and password text fields with the Entity Login (with attributes : userid and password) and then display another view with the informations associated with that user (1 to 1) relationship.

Can any one help me with how to validate the login password and then display only the information associated with that user?

Any help would be really appreciated. I am totally new to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a Fetch request against that Entity (you will need to modify this to fit your specific needs:

```
NSFetchRequest *request= [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username==%@ AND password==%@",self.UsernameTextField.Text, self.PasswordTextField.Text];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

... Do whatever you need to with the result (NSArray)

Comment: Thanks for the input... Could you tell me what do [request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:predicate]; mean??? and how can i use them to link to the destination view controller?

Comment: The best thing for you to do at this point is to go through some tutorials on this.  Ray Wenderlich has some great ones on basic Core Data, and the iTunesU Stanford courses are also really good.  The other option you have is to pay for training.  Lynda.com is a good place for that in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
// First view controller
#import "ViewController.h" 
#import "ViewController6578.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    NSArray *user;
}
- (IBAction)btt_reg:(id)sender;
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;

    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {

        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    }

    return context;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField

{

//    AppDelegate *appDelegate =

//        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self  managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request= [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"LogIn" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userName==%@",self.txt_user.text];

    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSManagedObject *manage = nil;

    NSError *error;

    user=[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

     if([user count]==0)
    {

        NSLog(@"user and password");

    }

    else

    {

        manage =user[0];

        _txt_pass.text = [manage valueForKey:@"password"];

    }
}

- (IBAction)btt_log:(id)sender {

    if((_txt_user.text.length == 0) || (_txt_pass.text.length==0))

    {

        NSLog(@"enter username and password");

    }

    else{

        NSLog(@"%@,Login successfull",_txt_user.text);

    }
}

- (IBAction)btt_reg:(id)sender {
    ViewController6578 *vc2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ndot"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];

}

@end

//second view controller

#import "ViewController6578.h"

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface ViewController6578 ()<UITextFieldDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController6578

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;

    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {

        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    }

    return context;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

/*

#pragma mark - Navigation



// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

}

*/

#pragma mark-delegate

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField

{

    [textField becomeFirstResponder];

    if(textField  == _txt_user)

    {

        [_txt_pass becomeFirstResponder];

    }

    else if(textField == _txt_pass)

    {

        [_txt_email becomeFirstResponder];

    }

   else  if(textField == _txt_email)

    {

        [_txt_email becomeFirstResponder];

    }

    else

    {

        [_txt_email resignFirstResponder];

    }

    return YES;       

}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string

{

    if (textField == _txt_user)

    {

        NSString *user =[_txt_user.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

        NSString *userRegex = @"^[A-Z0-9a-z]{6,10}$";

        NSPredicate *userTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", userRegex];

         if ([userTest evaluateWithObject:user] == YES)

         {

             _lbl1.text =@"";

         }

         else{

             _lbl1.text =@"not valid";

         }

    }

    if(textField ==_txt_pass)

    {

        NSString *pass =[_txt_pass.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];



        NSString *passRegex =@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)[a-zA-Z\\d]{8,16}$";

        NSPredicate *passTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",passRegex];

        if ([passTest evaluateWithObject:pass] == YES)

        {

            _lbl2.text =@"";

        }

        else{

            _lbl2.text =@"not valid";

        }
    }

    if(textField ==_txt_email)

    {

        NSString *email =[_txt_email.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

        NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,10}";

        NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];

        if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:email] == YES)

        {

            _lbl3.text =@"";

        }

        else{

            _lbl3.text =@"not valid";

        }

    }

    return YES;

}

- (IBAction)btt_save:(id)sender

{

    if((_txt_user.text.length==0) || (_txt_pass.text.length==0) || (_txt_email.text.length==0))

    {

        UIAlertController  *alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"title" message:@"please enter user,password,email" preferredStyle:UIAlertViewStyleDefault];

        UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction

                                    actionWithTitle:@"Yes, please"

                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault

                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)

                                    {
                                    }];

        UIAlertAction* cancelButton = [UIAlertAction

                                       actionWithTitle:@"No, thanks"

                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault

                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)

                                       {

                                       }];

        [alert addAction:yesButton];

        [alert addAction:cancelButton];

        [self presentViewController:alert animated:yesButton completion:nil];

    }

    else

    {


    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new managed object

    NSManagedObject *details = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LogIn" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [details setValue:self.txt_user.text forKey:@"userName"];

    [details setValue:self.txt_pass.text forKey:@"password"];

    [details setValue:self.txt_email.text forKey:@"emailAddress"];

    NSLog(@"12334%@",details);

    NSError *error = nil;

    _txt_user.text =@"";

    _txt_pass.text =@"";

    _txt_email.text =@"";
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ ",error .localizedDescription);

    }

}

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

- (IBAction)btt_cancel:(id)sender {

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//first view controller

#import "ViewController.h"

#import "SecondViewController.h"

#import "SecondTableViewCell.h"

#import "AppDelegate.h"





@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property(strong)NSMutableArray *company;



@end



@implementation ViewController



- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext

{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;

    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {

        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    }

    return context;

}



- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}



- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];



    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"CompanyDetails"];

    self.company = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];



    [self.tableview reloadData];

}



#pragma mark-datasource



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{

    // Return the number of sections.

    return 1;

}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return self.company.count;

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"sri";

    SecondTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];



    // Configure the cell...

    NSManagedObject *device = [self.company

                               objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    cell.lbl_c.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey:@"companyName"]];



    cell.lbl_e .text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" , [device valueForKey:@"empName"]];



    cell.lbl_s .text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey:@"salary"]];

    cell.img_g.image =[UIImage imageWithData:[device valueForKey:@"companyImage"]];



    return cell;

}



// delete



- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.

    return YES;

}





- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];



    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        // Delete object from database

        [context deleteObject:[self.company

                               objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];



        NSError *error = nil;

        if (![context save:&error]) {

            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);

            return;

        }



        // Remove device from table view

        [self.company removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self.tableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }

}



- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue"]) {

        NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.company objectAtIndex:[[self.tableview indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];

        SecondViewController *vc2 = segue.destinationViewController;

        vc2.device = selectedDevice;

    }

}



@end



//second view controller



#import "SecondViewController.h"

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>







@interface SecondViewController ()<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>



@end



@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize device;



-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext

{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;



    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {

        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    }

    return context;

}





- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];



    if (self.device) {

        [self.txt_c setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"companyName"]];

        [self.txt_e setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"empName"]];

        [self.txt_s setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"salary"]];

        self.img.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[self.device valueForKey:@"companyImage"]];



//        self.txt_stdname.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.obj valueForKey:@"studentName"]];

//        

//        self.txt_strrollno.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.obj valueForKey:@"studentRollno"]];

//        

//        self.txt_stddept.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.obj valueForKey:@"studentDepartment"]];





    }



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}



/*

#pragma mark - Navigation



// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

}

*/



- (IBAction)btt_save:(id)sender {



     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if(self.device)

    {

        [device setValue:self.txt_c.text forKey:@"companyName"];

        [device setValue:self.txt_e.text forKey:@"empName"];

        [device setValue:self.txt_s.text forKey:@"salary"];





        NSData *imgdata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.img.image, 0.0);

        [device setValue:imgdata forKey:@"companyImage"];





    }

    else

    {



     NSManagedObject *comdetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CompanyDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [comdetails setValue:self.txt_c.text forKey:@"companyName"];

    [comdetails setValue:self.txt_e.text forKey:@"empName"];

    [comdetails setValue:self.txt_s.text forKey:@"salary"];



    NSData *imgdata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.img.image, 0.0);

     [comdetails setValue:imgdata forKey:@"companyImage"];

    }



    NSError *error = nil;

    // Save the object to persistent store

    if (![context save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ ", error.localizedDescription);

    }

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}



- (IBAction)btt_gallery:(id)sender {



    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];





}



#pragma mark UIImagePickerControllerDelegate







- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker



         didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image



                   editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo



{



    self.img.image = image;



    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];



}







- (IBAction)btt_cancel:(id)sender {



    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "secondTableViewCell.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<NSURLConnectionDelegate,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSData *get_data;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *result_array;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *base_url = @"https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=909253&entity=album";

    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",base_url]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
#pragma mark- nsurlconnection delegate

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
{
    NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(nonnull NSURLResponse *)response
{

    NSLog(@"%@",response);
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(nonnull NSData *)data
{

    NSLog(@"88888%@",data);

    if ([data length])
    {
        self.get_data = [[NSData alloc]init];
        self.get_data =data;
        NSLog(@"%@",self.get_data);

    }


}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.get_data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
    NSLog(@"vijay%@",dict);


    if (!error)
    {

        NSArray *array = [dict valueForKey:@"results"];
        NSLog(@"1212%@",array);

        self.result_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        self.result_array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [_tableview reloadData];
                });
    }


}
#pragma mark -uitableview datasource

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.result_array.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    secondTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"sri"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[secondTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }

    cell.lbl1.text = [[self.result_array valueForKey:@"wrapperType"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lbl2.text = [[self.result_array valueForKey:@"artistName"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lbl3.text = [[self.result_array valueForKey:@"primaryGenreName"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // integer to string
    NSInteger artid = [[[self.result_array valueForKey:@"artistId"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue];

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)artid];

//        NSInteger release = [[[self.result_array valueForKey:@"releaseDate"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue];
//    
//        NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)release];
    //
//    cell.lbl3.text = str;
////    //      // float to string
//       float a = [[[self.result_array valueForKey:@"collectionPrice"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]floatValue];
//        NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",a];
//    
       cell.lbl4.text = str;

////
//    
    cell.img1.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[_result_array valueForKey:@"artworkUrl60"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]]];
//    
//    
//    
//    
//    
//    
   return cell;
}
//
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue" sender:self];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;



    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue"]) {
        //Do something

        NSIndexPath *index = [self.tableview indexPathForSelectedRow];


        SecondViewController *detailController = [segue destinationViewController];
       // detailController.txt2= [cricket objectAtIndex:index.row];



        detailController.imgg1= [UIImage imageNamed:[_result_array objectAtIndex:index.row]];



    }

}
@end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import "CollectionViewCell1234.h"

#import "ViewController6778.h"







@interface ViewController ()<NSURLConnectionDelegate,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UINavigationControllerDelegate>



@property (nonatomic ,strong)NSData *resultdata;

@property ( nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *array1;



@end



@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self webserviceCallingUsingGETMethod];

    _collectionview.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];





}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

#pragma mark- delegate

-(void)webserviceCallingUsingGETMethod

{

NSString *stringurl = @"https://itunes.apple.com/search?";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stringurl]];

NSString *params = @"term=jack+johnson&entity=musicVideo";

NSData *postdata = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];

[request setURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setHTTPBody:postdata];

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];



    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];



[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable connectionError) {



    if (connectionError) {

        NSLog(@"Error :%@", connectionError.localizedDescription);

        return;

    }



    if (data) {



        self.resultdata = data;

        NSError *error = nil;





        NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_resultdata options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];



        NSLog(@"RESULT :%@", result);



        NSArray *array = [result valueForKey:@"results"];

        _array1 =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        _array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];

        NSLog(@"122345%@",array);



        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



            [_collectionview reloadData];

        });



    }

}];





}







#pragma mark-collectionview delegate



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView

{

    return 1;

}





- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    return _array1.count;

}



- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    NSString *nschool = @"sri";

    CollectionViewCell1234 *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:nschool forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.imgview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[_array1 valueForKey:@"artworkUrl30"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]]];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    cell.lbl1.text = [[self.array1 valueForKey:@"wrapperType"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lbl2.text = [[self.array1 valueForKey:@"artistName"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lbl3.text = [[self.array1 valueForKey:@"releaseDate"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lbl4.text = [[self.array1 valueForKey:@"country"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lbl5.text = [[self.array1 valueForKey:@"currency"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lbl6.text = [[self.array1 valueForKey:@"trackName"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lbl7.text = [[self.array1 valueForKey:@"kind"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];





    NSInteger artid= [[[self.array1 valueForKey:@"artistId"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]integerValue];

    NSString *str1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)artid];

    cell.lbl8.text = str1;

    CGFloat   cp = [[[self.array1 valueForKey:@"collectionPrice"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]floatValue];

    NSString *str4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3f",cp];

    cell.lbl9.text  = str4;

   cell.lbl10.text = [[self.array1 valueForKey:@"collectionExplicitness"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lbl11.text = [[self.array1 valueForKey:@"primaryGenreName"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];





   NSInteger tracknum  = [[[self.array1 valueForKey:@"trackId"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]integerValue];

    NSString *str3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)tracknum];

    cell.lbl12.text = str3;

    cell.lbl13.text = [[self.array1 valueForKey:@"trackExplicitness"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    NSInteger tracknum1  =[[[self.array1 valueForKey:@"trackTimeMillis"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]integerValue];

    NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)tracknum1];



    cell.lbl14.text =str2;

    return cell;

}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue" sender:self];

}



- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue"])

    {

        ViewController6778 *vc2 = [segue destinationViewController];

        vc2.img1.images ;

    }

}

@end
```